# Repeated measure ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, terminology

I have tested male and female participants in one visual search task.

The task included 3 different types of displays (1 factor, 3 levels); meaning I have 3 means for each male or female participant. So the design is 2 (gender: f/m) x 3 (RT: M1/M2/M3). Is this analysis called a repeated measure ANOVA?

Comment: This is a crossed design: do M1/M2/M3 stand for individual or group means in each condition (type of displays)? (If these are individuals means, you would have an additional factor, e.g. number of trials or replicates.)

Comment: Thanks. yes each person has 3 means for responding to 3 different displays, it means that I have one whithin subject and 1 between subject factor. So I need to compare the interaction between gender and display type, main effect of gender and main effect of displays(I hope it makes sense), shall I call it mixed design ANOVA?